# Does the array “sum and/or sub” to `x`?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, performance, complexity-theory

**Goal**

I would like to write an algorithm (in `C`) which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` (`1` or `0`) depending whether the array `A` given in input can “sum and/or sub” to `x` (see below for clarification). Note that all values of `A` are integers bounded between [1,x-1] that were randomly (uniformly) sampled.

**Clarification and examples**

By “sum and/or sub”, I mean placing "+" and "-" in front of each element of array and summing over. Let's call this function `SumSub`.

```
int SumSub (int* A,int x)
{
...
}

SumSub({2,7,5},10)
```

should return `TRUE` as 7-2+5=10. You will note that the first element of `A` can also be taken as negative so that the order of elements in `A` does not matter.

```
SumSub({2,7,5,2},10)
```

should return `FALSE` as there is no way to  “sum and/or sub” the elements of `array` to reach the value of `x`. Please note, this means that all elements of `A` must be used.

**Complexity**

Let `n` be the length of `A`. Complexity of the problem is of order O(2^n) if one has to explore all possible combinations of pluses and minus. However, some combinations are more likely than others and therefore are worth being explored first (hoping the output will be `TRUE`). Typically, the combination which requires substracting all elements from the largest number is impossible (as all elements of `A` are lower than `x`). Also, if `n>x`, it makes no sense to try adding all the elements of `A`.

**Question**

How should I go about writing this function?

Comment: sounds like a typical knapsack problem. Is there a limit on the elements and size of array ?

Comment: I would like to use array of size as big as my ressources can handle (in terms of CPU time). The elements of `A` are bounded between [1,x-1], where `x` can be any unsigned integer.

Comment: Should *all* values from the array be used in the *sum and/or sub* operation?

Comment: @trincot yes, all values must be used

Comment: What makes this problem different from a math one can be shown in this case: (pretend `unsigned` is 8-bit for simplicity.)  Consider `SumSub({250, 250, 5, 5} 254)`.. This is true for C as `unsigned` overflow is well defined - just add the 4 elements.  It is false in math with its unlimited range.
It is uncertain what OP wants, a math solution or a C one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem's solution is indeed exponential as you said. BUT with the given range[1,x-1] for numbers in A[] you can make the solution polynomial. There is a very simple dynamic programming solution.

With the order:

Time Complexity: O(n^2*x)

Memory Complexity: O(n^2*x)

where, n=num of elements in A[]

You need to use dynamic programming approach for this

You know the min,max range that can be made in in the range [-n*x,n*x]. Create a 2d array of size (n)X(2*n*x+1). Lets call this dp[][]

dp[i][j] = taking all elements of A[] from [0..i-1] whether its possible to make the value j

so

dp[10][3] = 1 means taking first 10 elements of A[] we CAN create the value 3

dp[10][3] = 0 means taking first 10 elements of A[] we can NOT create the value 3

Here is a kind of pseudo code for this:

```
int SumSub (int* A,int x)
{
    bool dp[][];//set all values of this array 0
    dp[0][0] = true;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        int val = A[i-1];
        for(j=-n*x;j<=n*x;j++) {
            dp[i][j]=dp[ i-1 ][ j + val ] | dp[ i-1 ][ j - val ];
        }
    }
    return dp[n][x];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your problem can be reduced to [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is NP-Complete. Thus the exponential solution can't be avoided.

Comment: The problem whose answer is always NO can also "be reduced to subset-sum problem which is NP-Complete." ​ (Just output `{2,3},4`.) ​ Thus the existence of such a reduction does not show any hardness whatsoever for Remi.b's problem. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is NP-complete even when x is restricted to the value 0, so don't expect a polynomial-time algorithm.  To show this I'll give a simple reduction from the NP-hard [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which asks whether a given multiset of positive integers can be partitioned into two parts having equal sums:

Suppose we have an instance of the Partition Problem consisting of n positive integers B_1, ..., B_n.  Create from this an instance of your problem in which A_i = B_i for each 1 <= i <= n, and set x = 0.

Clearly if there is a partition of B into two parts C and D having equal sums, then there is also a solution to the instance of your problem: Put a `+` in front of every number in C, and a `-` in front of every number in D (or the other way round).  Since C and D have equal sums, this expression must equal 0.

OTOH, if the solution to the instance of your problem that we just created is YES (TRUE), then we can easily create a partition of B into two parts having equal sums: just put all the positive terms in one part (say, C), and all the negative terms (without the preceding `-` of course) in the other (say, D).  Since we know that the total value of the expression is 0, it must be that the sum of the (positive) numbers in C is equal to the (negated) sum of the numbers in D.

Thus a YES to either problem instance implies a YES to the other problem instance, which in turn implies that a NO to either problem instance implies a NO to the other problem instance -- that is, the two problem instances have equal solutions.  Thus if it were possible to solve your problem in polynomial time, it would be possible to solve the NP-hard Partition Problem in polynomial time too, by constructing the above instance of your problem, solving it with your poly-time algorithm, and reporting the result it gives.